# Vue router and jQuery plugins

Tags: jquery, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Scene: Front-end design is made using bootstrap and jQuery (with many plugins and custom functions). Now I'm supposed to use the design to integrate on SPA using Vue and Laravel.

Problem: All document.ready functions of jquery works fine when page is loaded for the first time, but when page is rendered using vue router the functions aren't triggered. Since the design is created by another designer I don't want to use npm to install jquery dependencies and keep theme assets separate in public folder.

How can I solve the problem and what may be the best practice to integrate a jquery based theme with vue.

Comment: You have conflicting design patterns on your hands with this one. Vue router providers many different mechanisms for leveraging Vue lifecycle hooks as well as some of it's own. As you said, document.ready is good for the page load only. You're going to have to wrap everything in a callable function or move it into components `created`, `mounted`, activated`, `deactivated` hooks. Personally, I would get rid of the jQuery dependency and follow the Vue framework design patterns. You'll be much happier in the long run.

Comment: @btl Thanks I will try to work  with mounted and created now. The thing is I got back-end development and theme integration project for a pre-made theme so it's getting pretty difficult not to neglect the dependencies  as it's what client requires.
Is there a way to identify if the page is visited using full url on browser or by clicking vue router link?

Comment: Yes, you can use `PerformanceNavigation` to determine the context in which your page has been visited. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceNavigation

Comment: @btl that is what i needed. Kudos to you sir. Thankyou